# Where can i find the compatible versions for Apache kafka brokers and Apache kafka-clients

Tags: apache-kafka

Where can i find the compatible versions for Apache kafka brokers and Apache kafka-clients.I need to upgrade kafka clients version to 3.4.0 but is it supported by Apache kafka broker 3.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

After approx Kafka 1.0.0, all client features are completely backwards compatible, even partially down to 0.10.2

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

If you're using anything older, I strongly recommend following the documentation on upgrades